# HttpWebRequest redirect with cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I know a lot of questions have been asked about HttpWebRequest. However, I can't find any answer for the problem I'm having.

I need to mimic the way browsers redirect URLs. My code works fine but not for the URL below:

My code:

```
sURL = "http://ad2.adfarm1.adition.com/redi*lid=689397953768/sid=404178/kid=253598/bid=847344/c=33349/keyword=/sr=0/clickurl=&ClickTarget=_blank&";
CookieContainer oCookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = oCookies;
myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";    
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
myHttpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-GB";
myHttpWebRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
sNewURL = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader("Location");
```

Fiddler by IE, Request:

```
GET http://ad2.adfarm1.adition.com/redi*lid=689397953768/sid=404178/kid=253598/bid=847344/c=33349/keyword=/sr=0/clickurl=&ClickTarget=_blank& HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: ad2.adfarm1.adition.com
Cookie: fc3=101c3; co=1; UserID1=19177152736; lv_248940=w=470167|t=1321974830; lv_249431=w=125082|t=1321974853; lc_253598=w=404178|t=1321977996
```

Fiddler by code, Request:

```
GET http://ad2.adfarm1.adition.com/redi*lid=689397953768/sid=404178/kid=253598/bid=847344/c=33349/keyword=/sr=0/clickurl=&ClickTarget=_blank& HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: ad2.adfarm1.adition.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Fiddler by IE, Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: ADITIONSERVER v1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 17:37:39 +0100
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Location: &ClickTarget=_blank&
P3P: policyref="http://imagesrv.adition.com/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMo OUR NOR COM"
Set-Cookie: co=1; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2025 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.adfarm1.adition.com
Set-Cookie: UserID1=19177152736; expires=Sun, 20-May-2012 18:37:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.adfarm1.adition.com
Set-Cookie: lc_253598=w=404178|t=1321979859; expires=Tue, 22-Nov-2011 18:07:39 GMT; path=/; domain=.adfarm1.adition.com
```

Fiddler by code, Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: ADITIONSERVER v1.0
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2011 18:07:39 +0100
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Location: http://ad2.adfarm1.adition.com:80/redi?co=1&bid=847344&c=33349&keyword=&kid=253598&lid=689397953768&sid=404178&sr=0&clickurl=%26ClickTarget%3D%5Fblank%26
P3P: policyref="http://imagesrv.adition.com/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMo OUR NOR COM"
Set-Cookie: co=1; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2025 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.adfarm1.adition.com
```

As you can see, the location value I got from the code is different from IE. The only difference I can see from Fiddler is the cookies are not been send by the request. However, where are those cookies coming from and how can I set them?

Many thanks,

Comment: Did you ensure your IE didn't have any cookies when you tried your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies it is sending when using IE must have been saved in your session or on your hd during a previous request which responded with a Set-Cookie header.

If you want to manually set cookies to send with your initial request you would do something like this.

```
CookieContainer oCookies = new CookieContainer();
            CookieCollection cookieGroup = new CookieCollection();
            Cookie userId = new Cookie("UserID1","19177152736", "/", ".adfarm1.adition.com");
            cookieGroup.Add(userId);
            oCookies.Add(cookieGroup);
```

then add it to your HTTPWebRequest like this.

```
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = oCookies;
```

If you want to include the cookies in any subsequent requests just make sure to set that httpWebRequests CookieContainer to oCookies.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would not need to have any cookies set or sent from your initial request.

If you've never been to that URL you shouldn't have any cookies from it.

I've done a ton of web scraping via the HttpRequestObject and from what I can remember I never needed to set any cookies.

Your CookieContainer object would be populated from the 1st response and you would use that on  future requests to maintain state.

I would clear your cache and modify your request until it matches exactly in fiddler.

Also, from what I can remember redirects are taken care and captured in the response.

I'll look through some code when I get home and post any additional help if I can.

- Jon