# C# HttpWebRequest Cookies not transmitted

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to transmit two manually created Cookies with a initial request **from the client to a server** (no response available, where the Cookies could be extracted) using the following code (as discussed e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245034/httpwebrequest-redirect-with-cookies))

```
HttpWebRequest request = 
      (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
      "https://intra.group.net:5115/app/search.do");

//...

CookieContainer oCookies = new CookieContainer();
CookieCollection cookieGroup = new CookieCollection();
Cookie c1 = new Cookie("name1", "value1", "/", ".intra.group.net");
Cookie c2 = new Cookie("name2", "value2", "/", ".intra.group.net");
cookieGroup.Add(c1);
cookieGroup.Add(c2);
oCookies.Add(cookieGroup);
request.CookieContainer = oCookies;
```

But raw communication doesn't contain (according to Fiddler) any Cookie data. Any suggestions why they are missing? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's some synchronize problem. Sometimes the problem is the HttpOnly cookies that are missing from Document.Cookie for security reasons.You can try this solution [here](http://ycouriel.blogspot.com/2010/07/webbrowser-and-httpwebrequest-cookies.html).

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you are blaming a synchronization problem of request and response. But I don't have any request to extract the cookies from. I'm trying to create them programatically and attach them to the first communication happening.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are received in the HttpWebRequest, not sent.

They are Sent with the WebReponse.

-> HttpContext.Current.Request : Contains Received Cookies

-> HttpContext.Current.Response: Contains cookies sent back to browser.

Add your cookies to the response instead of the request.

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["someCookie"]
if (cookie != null)
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove(cookie);

HttpCookie updatedCookier = new HttpCookie....
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(updatedCookie);
```

Comment: Isn't the ´HttpContext´ a server thing? I'm on the Client side and need to transmit two Cookies along with the first "request" from the client to the server. Thank you

Comment: Yes, but it applies to the client as well.

If the server doesn't accept/respect the cookie you are trying to set, then it won't be in the response and won't be set in the browser.  

If you put a cookie in a request and send the request to the server, the server can flush all the cookies causing the response to not set any cookies.  Because cookies are set in the browser with the response.  

It's pretty common for search api's, web services, etc, to flush the cookies and headers before responding to produce clean responses.

Do you have control over the /app/search.do code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for you but a few months back i was doing something similar where i manually paste cookies in the HttpWebrequest and it worked so try this:

Assuming postReq= WebRequest.

```
HttpWebRequest request =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("SomeUrl");
postReq.Headers.Add("Cookie: PREF=ID=17337a16083851b1:");// You can get this from fiddler
```

Post it all in one line....